# How to get to shoulders localization on image photo?

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision

I have to localize from video where the shoulders of a person are in a movie.
Do have any advice on how to get to this?

I thought about corner detection or some kind of shape detection. But I'm still not sure what next. We can treat video like image sequence (I wrote this, but I think is obvious)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Luckily, the shoulders are usually attached to the head...

I have used the Dalal-Triggs algorithm [(Wikipedia)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram_of_oriented_gradients)  to detect head+shoulders of all persons facing the camera.
Basically, you train a linear SVM on positive examples in which the head+shoulders are marked, and on negative examples that do not contain these body parts. The descriptor is a Histogram of Gradients (HOG) which tells you what edge directions are dominant in each cell of the descriptor. I found that their normalization scheme is very important in dealing with non-uniform lighting.

With enough examples, the linear SVM will provide you with a plane normal that can be interpreted as a descriptor: you can visualize the meaning of the positive weights, and see that they outline the profile of head+shoulders. Likewise, the negative weights will belong to the areas outside the body, and/or directions orthogonal to the profile edges.

You can apply the linear SVM classifier on each image efficiently at multiple scales and aspect ratios, and find the image patch with best response. This should give you the location of the head and shoulders (it will not be exact, though)